# Есть ли библиотеки для работы с HTTP на С?

Tags: c, веб-программирование

Здравствуйте! Решил заняться С, совсем в нём новичёк, синтаксис освоил, хочу попробовать сделать простенькое веб-приложение. Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли какая-нибудь библиотека для обработки HTTP запросов на подобии "net/http" в Go? Если нет, то как реализовать какой-нибудь hello world в браузере?

Слишком привык к высокому уровню, простите.

Comment: а зачем на С писать в вебе? технологий тьма, возьми Ruby on Rails например - заводится с пол-оборота, все фичи последние вобрал. Или рнр какое-нибудь - по фреймворкам печаль а на чистом сегодня уже хело ворлд слепишь.

Comment: Я на Lаravel (PHP) пишу долго, хочу понять как оно всё изнутри работает, поэтому учу С.

Comment: если долго, тогда сорян.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[libhttp](https://www.libhttp.org/) - олдскульно, даже сайт отдает тихим ламповым звуком

Comment: Спасибо огромное!